# I can't convert image to monochrome bitmap with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, bmp

I'm trying to transform an image to monochrome bmp and its not working. 
I tried writing:

magick.exe convert c:\users\asus\desktop\image.jpg -monochrome c:\image.bmp

and I got the following error

convert: UnableToOpenConfigureFile `delegates.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/702.
convert: UnableToOpenModuleFile 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPEG_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/675.
convert: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat`JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: NoImagesDefined `c:\image.bmp' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3282.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In IM 7, use magick, not magick convert. Not likely to make a difference. What do you get from `magick.exe -version`. Perhaps you are missing some delegates. How did you install ImageMagick?

Comment: I tried and it still didn't work. But that's okay, I'm using graphicsmagick now.